# Pointer syntax in a function

Tags: c, pointers

I thought I understood pointer syntax but there are small occurrences that throw me off, for instance:

```
int *ptr;
int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int *arrayEnd = array + n;

for (ptr = array; ptr < arrayEnd; ++ptr)
    sum += *ptr;

return sum;
```

How come we do `ptr = array` instead of `*ptr = array` when defining the `for` loop?

I also don't understand why when an argument to a function is a pointer, we don't use the asterisk.

I see this `function(ptr);` in books, but why not this: `function(*ptr);`.

Comment: Please provide the declaration of `array`. Also, I think `sum += *ptr;` should be either indented or inside `{}`.

Comment: The use of `func(ptr)` and `func(*ptr)` can both be legitimate, but they do different things. `func(ptr)` passes the address that `ptr` contains, while `func(*ptr)` passes the value found at the address which `ptr` contains.

Comment: Where on earth did `n` and `sum` come from? I assume they're both just `int`s?

Comment: `function(ptr);` doesn't make any sense. There's no return type for `function` and no type at all for `ptr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's begin with the first line of your code:

```
int *ptr;
```

If you had declared

```
int a;
```

What would it mean? It would mean `a` is an `int`. Similarly, since you have declared `int *ptr;`, it means that `*ptr` is an `int`.

If `*ptr` is an `int`, what is `ptr`? `ptr` (without the star) is a *pointer to an* `int`. A *pointer* is a variable that holds the address of a value. In this case, the pointer is a pointer to an `int`, which means the value at the address held by `ptr` is an `int`.

Then you have `int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};`. When you declare and define an array, the array identifier (the name of the array) tells you where the array lives in memory. When used in any expression, the name of the array decays to the address of the first element of the array.

So when you have

```
ptr = array;
```

you are assigning the address of the first element of the array to the pointer `ptr`. Since this is an array of `int`, you are assigning the address of an `int` to a variable which can hold the address of an `int`. The left- and right-hand side of the assignment are the same kind of value.

Why `ptr` and not `*ptr`? What is `*` in this instance? It is the unary dereference / indirection operator. So

```
*ptr = array;
```

would mean: take the value on the right-hand side, and *replace the value at the address held by* `ptr` *with this right-hand side value*. This is wrong for two reasons.

1. `array` is an address. It is not exactly an integer value. It's just a location in memory. Sure, that location can be represented by an integer, the way a location in the US can be represented by an integer zip code, but just as you don't typically care what the numerical value of a zip code is, you probably don't really care what the integer value of a given memory address is either.
2. `ptr` is uninitialized. To go back to our earlier example: `int a;`. What is the value of `a`? We haven't set a value for it yet, so it has just garbage. Similarly, `ptr` isn't pointing to anything yet. It *can* point to an integer, but we haven't yet told it what integer to point to. There is no address held at `ptr`. We can't say "replace the current value pointed to by `ptr` by this new value", because `ptr` isn't yet pointing to any value at all; we haven't told it where to point to begin with.

To sum up: By writing `ptr = array;` what you are doing is precisely correct--assigning a pointer to an `int` to a variable of type `pointer to an int`. By writing `*ptr = array;` you would be assigning an address to an integer, which is probably not what you mean to do; and secondly, since the integer itself is not allocated anywhere in memory, the assignment has nowhere to go.

That's why `ptr = array;` is correct, and `*ptr = array` would be quite wrong.

The question about function pointers is a separate one, so please ask a different question about `func(ptr)` vs. `func(*ptr)`.

Comment: Fantastic explanation.  Thank you really.  so when we do ptr = array, we are storing the address of the first array element into ptr?  ++ptr will then make ptr point to  the address of array[1], array[2], etc.?  When we do ptr<arrayEnd we are comparing the address stored in ptr to the address stored in arrayEnd (which is array[4])?

Comment: @somid You are correct. `array` has four elements, `array[0]` through `array[3]`. The address of the first is `array`, i.e., `array + 0`. The address of the last is `array + 3`. So `array + 4`, or `arrayEnd`, is just outside the bounds of the array. So you want to continue only as long as `ptr` is less than that, and to stop once `ptr` reaches there, which is exactly what your code does.

Answer (score 3):

You can transform a traditional, index-based iteration into one using only pointer arithmetic like this:

```
T array[N];

// traditional:

for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
{
    foo(array[i]);
}

// using pointer arithmetic

for (T * p = array; p != array + N; ++p)
{
    foo(*p);
}
```

The pointer `T * p = array` is obtained via the decay of an array name to a pointer to its first element. The connection between the two forms is the fundamental identity `array[i]` == `*(array + i)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *ptr, i;
int array[20];

ptr  = &i;        // make sure ptr points somewhere valid
ptr  = array;     // put the address of array[0] in the variable ptr
*ptr = array;     // put the address of array[0] into the location ptr points to
ptr  = array[0];  // put the integer in array[0] into the variable ptr
*ptr = array[0];  // put the integer in array[0] into the location ptr points to.
```

Comment: I noticed that if I do int *ptr; then do *ptr=array; I get a warning saying the variable ptr is uninitialized, but ptr=array works fine.

Comment: Right, because you haven't put an address in `ptr` in your code above. Since `ptr` hasn't been assigned a value, you can't depend on it pointing to a valid memory address, and the compiler warns you. I put the assignment in (`ptr = &i`) to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your suggested code:

```
*ptr = array
```

Remember that here, `*` is the indirection operator. It returns the object at the memory location to which the pointer points. Also, in this context `array` is converted to a pointer. So the above line assigns a **pointer** (i.e. a memory address) to the object `ptr` **points to**. This can only be valid if `ptr` points to a pointer. However, `ptr` points to an `int` instead.

On the other hand `ptr = array` is correct because assigns `ptr` to point to the first element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have code like below.

```
int x=10;
```

Here x is a variable that holds a value 10. The variable x is nothing but a label to some memory address.

```
        x
    +-------+
    |  10   |    4050 which is x
    +-------+
```

So value 10 is stored in 4050. Its always hard to remember memory address. So you make it easy by naming it and using that name.Here x is nothing but a label to memory address 4050.

```
int *x_ptr;
```

Here x_ptr is a pointer variable that can store memory address of any integer variable.

```
   +-------+
   |  GBV  |   5000 which is x_ptr
   +-------+
```

Here x_ptr is a label for address 5000. Initially the variable will contain Garbage Value(GBV).

```
x_ptr = &x;
```

The above statement stores address of x in x_ptr.

```
   +-------+
   |  4050 |   5000
   +-------+
 x_ptr = &x = 4050
 printf("%u",x_ptr); // 4050
 printf("%d", *x_ptr); // 10

 *x_ptr = *(4050) = valueAt(4050) =  10
```

Let us now discuss about your code.

```
int *ptr;

+-------+
|  GBV  |   6000 which is ptr
+-------+

int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};

+-----------+
|     1     |    7824 which is array+0 or array[0]
+-----------+
|     2     |    7828 which is array+1 or array[1]
+-----------+
|     3     |    7832 which is array+2 or array[2]
+-----------+
|     4     |    7836 which is array+3 or array[3]
+-----------+
```

Here array = 7824

```
int *arrayEnd = array + n;
```

Incrementation with memory location will increase no of bytes based on the data type.

```
array+0 = 7824 + 0 = 7824
array+1 = 7824 + 1(4 bytes in case of integer) = 7824 + 4 = 7828
when n=4
    arrayEnd = 7824 + 16 =  7840
+-------+
|  7840 |   6010 which is arrayEnd
+-------+

for (ptr = array; ptr < arrayEnd; ++ptr)
   sum += *ptr;
```

Here ptr is initialized with array's base address(7824). So 7824 will be stored in memory 6000.

```
  6000             6000    
+-------+        +-------+
|  GBV  |   =>   | 7824  |   6000 which is ptr
+-------+        +-------+
```

so now ptr = 7824

```
For Loop
+-------+--------------+-------------+    
|  ptr  |   *ptr       | sum + =*ptr |  // 7824 < 7840
+-------+--------------+-------------+
|  7824 | *(7824) = 1  |  sum += 1   |  // 7828 < 7840
+-------+--------------+-------------+
|  7828 | *(7828) = 2  |  sum += 2   |  // 7832 < 7840
+-------+--------------+-------------+
|  7832 | *(7832) = 3  |  sum += 3   |  // 7836 < 7840
+-------+--------------+-------------+
|  7836 | *(7836) = 4  |  sum += 4   |  // 7840 !< 7840 so loop terminates
+-------+--------------+-------------+
```

Why ptr = array instead of *ptr = array?

```
valueAt(*) has to be used when you have to store some value in the memory address.

ptr= array; //initializing base address of array to ptr.

  6000             6000    
+-------+        +-------+
|  GBV  |   =>   | 7824  |   6000 which is ptr
+-------+        +-------+

*ptr = array; // ptr already has a address pointed to, and you store array's base address inside that memory location.

  6000     
+-------+  
|  GBV  |    *ptr= *(GBV) = Unknown = array  // No guarantee that GBV is a proper memory address
+-------+
```

if ptr already has some proper memory address say 1000, then it is like

```
  6000     
+-------+  
| 1000  |    *ptr= *(1000) = valueAt(1000) = array 
+-------+  

which makes

  1000     
+-------+  
| 7824  |    
+-------+
```

Simple example with multi pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    int *y=&x;
    int **z=&y;
    printf("%d --> %d --> %d",x,*y,**z); 
    return 0;
}

OUTPUT:
   10 --> 10 --> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the asterisk meaning is different in definiton. when you write:

```
int *arrayEnd = array + n;
```

it is actualy the same as:

```
int *arrayEnd;
arrayEnd = array + n;
```

In both cases you initialize the address of the pointer and not the value referenced by the pointer

Also note that when you define an array the array name can be considered as the first memory location of the array while the number in brackets is its offset i.e. the next two lines are the same:

```
ptr = array;
ptr = &array[0];
```

and also the next two lines:

```
array[2] = 5;
*(array+2) = 5;
```

Funny fact about the last example is that it can explain you can sometimes write:
`2[array]` instead of `array[2]` as `*(2+array)` is the same as `*(array+2)`

So when you write:

```
int *ptr;
int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int *arrayEnd = array + n;

for (ptr = array; ptr < arrayEnd; ++ptr)
    sum += *ptr;

return sum;
```

the third line placed the memory address of the last `array` element in a variable called `arrayEnd`

the `for` loop is running from the first `array` location to the last `array` location

the `sum` adds the array elements